# Erro ao usar include

Tags: php

Tenho dois arquivos php que retornam um `echo` com uma tabela. Funcionam ok.

gestanteCadastrada.php

```
echo '<h2>Gestantes Cadastradas</h2>';
echo '<table class="table table-striped">';
echo '<tr><th style="text-align:center;">Unidade</th><th style="text-align:center;">Gestante</th><th style="text-align:center;">Competência</th></tr>';

$total = 0;
$totalPrazo = 0;
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if ($row['diferenca'] > 0){
    echo "<tr style='background-color:red; color:white'><td>".$row['nu_cnes']." - ".$row['unidade']."</td><td>".$row['nome']."</td><td>".str_pad($row['mes'], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."/".$row['ano']."</td></tr>";
    $totalPrazo ++;
  }else{
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['nu_cnes']." - ".$row['unidade']."</td><td>".$row['nome']."</td><td>".str_pad($row['mes'], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."/".$row['ano']."</td></tr>";
  }
  $total ++;
}

echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>TOTAL DE GESTANTES CADASTRADAS</td><td>".$total."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>TOTAL DE GESTANTES CADASTRADAS INDEVIDAMENTE</td><td>".$totalPrazo."</td></tr>";
echo '</table>';
```

gestanteAcompanhada.php

```
echo '<h2>Gestantes Acompanhadas pelo ACS</h2>';
echo '<table class="table table-striped">';
echo '<tr><th style="text-align:center;">Unidade</th><th style="text-align:center;">Gestante</th><th style="text-align:center;">Competência</th></tr>';

$total = 0;
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<tr><td>".$row['nu_cnes']." - ".$row['no_equipe']."</td><td>".$row['no_cidadao']."</td><td>".$row['count']."</td></tr>";
  $total += $row['count'];
}

echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>TOTAL DE GESTANTES ACOMPANHADAS</td><td>".$total."</td></tr>";
echo '</table>';
```

E tenho um arquivo `index.php` que chama os dois assim:

```
include 'functions/gestanteCadastrada.php';
include 'functions/gestanteAcompanhada.php';
```

Tudo funciona bem, porém, o que quero é que o arquivo gestanteCadastrada.php chame o arquivo gestanteAcompanhada.php dessa forma:

```
include 'gestanteAcompanhada.php?gestanteCadastrada='.$total;
//veja que ele acrescenta uma variável à url
```

Porém estou recebendo erro de arquivo não encontrado:

> Warning: include(gestanteAcompanhada.php?gestanteCadastrada=8): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\relatorio\functions\gestanteCadastrada.php on line 57

E o arquivo está no local correto. O que pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendo, você não pode dar um include passando parâmetros.
Quando você da um include ele procura um arquivo no servidor e não o executa como se estivesse na web. Por isso, não vai encontrar um arquivo chamado "gestanteAcompanhada.php?gestanteCadastrada=8".

Edit: Você pode resolver seu caso com sessions, ou até chamando o arquivo como um serviço.

Comment: Que pena. Alguma sugestão de como contornar isso?

Comment: Bom, no exemplo que deu acima, acho que se só inserir o arquivo, sem parâmetros, daria certo pois de qualquer forma, você não está usando esta informação na página né? Aliás, está zerando a variável total... Mas se for o caso de usar o parâmetro, você pode usar uma sessão, onde a página a ser incluída lê a sessão e pega o valor, ou pode chamar só essa página como uma requisição web, uma gambi pra serviço entende?

Comment: Consegui resolver utilizando Sessions. Valeuuu. Pode alterar sua resposta que eu te dou os pontos

Comment: Valeu mann. Abraços.